# An alternative to backtracking

Tags: algorithm

I am developing a space optimisation software. It should be able to arrange small volumes in a larger space in an optimial way. With some constraints such as one volume cannot be moved or should "lie" on the inside face of another, or it cannot be topped by another, etc...

Every volume is represented as a 3d axis-aligned-bounding-box, or a group of smaller 3d AABB (which assemble into a more complex volume).

I've been thinking on using backtracking to solve this problem (especially the branch and bound technique) but it gets faaaar too greedy in term of speed as much as in term of memory (even for a over-simpified use).

Does anyone know an alternative technique that would suit this problem?

I'm out of idea... But i'm sure these kind of software exist so there is a way (which i don't know about).

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In a perfect parrotisable world, all problemns may be camels. But hold your horses, things may get fishy ...

Comment: i didn't really get what you were saying...

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are "solutions" to this problem, and they are big-big business. Solving this problem well can earn you a lot of money as it is NP-hard and immensly useful.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

My first thought was to rephrase the problem in a discrete linear programming fashion, which has already been done, see the reference below if you have access.

Mhand Hifi, Imed Kacem, Stephane Negre, Lei Wu (2010) "A Linear Programming Approach for the Three-Dimensional Bin-Packing Problem" Electronic Notes in Discrete Mathematics, 36, 993–1000

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at Dynamic Programming approach if you havent looked already. Your problem sounds similar to "Cutting Cloth" problem which is a typical Dynamic Programming problem. Here is Cutting Cloth problem :

> Cutting cloth. You are given a rectangular piece of cloth with
>   dimensions X  Y , where X and Y are positive integers, and a list of
>   n products that can be made using the cloth. For each product i 2 [1;
>   n] you know that a rectangle of cloth of dimensions ai  bi is needed
>   and that the final selling price of the product is ci . Assume the
>   ai, bi, and ci are all positive integers. You have a machine that can
>   cut any rectangular piece of cloth into two pieces either horizontally
>   or vertically. Design an algorithm that determines the best return on
>   the X  Y piece of cloth, that is, a strategy for cutting the cloth so
>   that the products made from the resulting pieces give the maximum sum
>   of selling prices. You are free to make as many copies of a given
>   product as you wish, or none if desired.

Here is how i will divide Cutting Cloth problem into Subproblems :

```
V( i,j) = max { V(i - ai, j- bi ) + ci,
                V(i - bi, j - ai ) + ci
              }
```

Comment: What makes the cutting cloth problem a bit easier is that it always cuts the cloth *all the way across*, so you always wind up with nice, regular rectangles left over.  If the machine was able to make cuts of arbitrary length, the problem would be a bit harder -- and solutions which much greater value could be found.